# Ruby regular expression (regex) to get JSON data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, google-maps, expression

I want to get `lat` and `lon` from `user_location` column using the regular expression while in database the column data is stored in JSON format as `{"lon":74.46586,"lat":31.523199}`.
I get the values using the split method which is not a good practice, as it following.

`lon = @session_request.user_location.split(',').first.split('=>').last.chomp('}').to_f`
and
`lat = @session_request.user_location.split(',').last.split('=>').last.chomp('}').to_f`

I want to make the regular expression of the above code.

from my terminal the following results occurs

> *pry(#<#Class:0x00005649d78e6918>)> location = @session_request.user_location**

> => "{"lon"=>74.43935992994889, "lat"=>31.52203286189515}"

> pry(#<#Class:0x00005649d78e6918>)> lon = location.split(',').first.split('=>').last.chomp('}')

> => "74.43935992994889"

> pry(#<#Class:0x00005649d78e6918>)> lat = location.split(',').last.split('=>').last.chomp('}')

> => "31.52203286189515"

regular expression to get the values or any better solution ??

Comment: If you're using Postgres then there are built in methods for querying JSON, you don't need Regex. See [active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb)

Answer (score 0):

You can do following easily if you are using postgresql with Jsonb not sure may json would do same.

```
location = @session_request.user_location
```

lon = location["lon"]
lat = location["lat"]

```
I was tested on my database and rails by doing following
```

meta = table.metadata = {"lon":74.46586,"lat":31.523199}

```
puts meta["lon"]
74.46586
```

But if you want regex to do it, you can do following.

```
lon, lan = location.scan(/(\d+\.\d+)/)
```